# How to get an attribute from Multiple Class (?)

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

I want to send value attributes from `.submitApp` with ajax. this class does not document ready. this class is made by event onclick.

```
function setApp(schedule_id, sesi_id, no_id, waktu)
    {
        if (document.querySelector('.submit_sesi').contains(document.querySelector('.no'+no_id))) {
            alert('this session have been setted');
        }else{
            let para = document.createElement("button");
            para.innerHTML="Sesi "+waktu+" Diset";
            para.className+="btn submitApp btn-info no"+no_id+"";
            para.setAttribute("onclick", "delApp('"+sesi_id+"','"+waktu+"','"+no_id+"')");
            para.setAttribute("data1", schedule_id);
            para.setAttribute("data2", sesi_id);
            para.setAttribute("data3", no_id);
            let element = document.querySelector(".submit_sesi");
            element.appendChild(para);
        }
    }
```

and then after that i want to ajax it in submitApp function onclick. the problem is in this function.

i've tried like this to get attributes on multiple `.submitApp`

```
function submitApp () {
    var data1;
    var data2;
    var data3;
    var arrData = [];
    $.each($('.submitApp'), function(index, val) {
        arrData.push($('.submitApp'));
    });

   $.each(arrData, function(index, val) {
      data1 = arrData.attr('data1');
      data2 = arrData.attr('data2');
      data3 = arrData.attr('data3');
   });

   console.log(data1+data2+data3);

  //ajax start here...
}
```

it give me error arrData.attr() is not a function.

here's my html markup

```
<div class="submit_sesi">
    <button class="btn btn-pill btn-primary submitAppointment" onclick="submitApp()">Submit Appointment</button>
</div>
```

I want to get the attributes `data1, data2, data3` from multiple `.submitApp`, and then pass it to the ajax and send it to the controller. each `data1, data2, data3` in class `.submitApp` is different. I use laravel

Comment: It will give you an error as you are already traversing over the `arrData` you might wanna do `val.attr('data'+i)`

Comment: where do i get it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to use the index there.
It will be like this:

I changed your push to push($this)
and created a new array to have the data1, data2, data3 from different elements

```
    function submitApp () {
    var data1;
    var data2;
    var data3;
    var arrData = [];
    var arrresult = [];
    $.each($('.submitApp'), function(index, val) {
        arrData.push($(this));
    });

$.each(arrData, function(index, val) {
      arrresult[index]=[];
      arrresult[index][0] = val.attr('data1');
      arrresult[index][1] = val.attr('data2');
      arrresult[index][2] = val.attr('data3');
   });
    console.dir(arrresult);

  //ajax start here...
}
```

Comment: well, it doesn't show the error, but the output just one `.submitApp`. not multiple

Comment: What is your expected output? At your code you are overwriting data1, data2, data3.

Comment: what i expected is to get the attributes from each `.submitApp`. in each `.submitApp` class the data1, data2, and data3 is different

Comment: it gives me error `TypeError: arrresult[index] is undefined`

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to copy one line there. I edited it and it should works fine.

Comment: thank you, sir, this is what I wanted! but how to pass it to ajax data:{} option? should I each function again?

Comment: Or you can use a for loop based on arrresult length and take the three datas from there.

Comment: well, I've tried to pass it to the controller right away. and then after that, i use for each in the controller, and it works. thank you sir !

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine for you:

```
function submitApp(){
    var data1 = [];
    var data2 = [];
    var data3 = [];

    $(".submitApp").each(function(i, elem){
        data1.push($(elem).attr("data1"));
        data2.push($(elem).attr("data2"));
        data3.push($(elem).attr("data3"));
    });

    console.log(data1, data2, data3);
}
```

Comment: it gives me an error `SyntaxError: expected expression got ']'` on data[1] = $(elem.attr("data1"); line

Comment: Did you use `data1[]` or `data[1]` because the second one is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you! your answer is correct but what I wanted is like @Fabio Assuncao answer.